# Is there such a thing as IMAP for podcasts?

Tags: synchronization, imap, podcast

Is there such a thing as IMAP for podcasts?

I own a desktop, laptop, iPod, smartphone and a web-client all downloading StackOverflow Podcasts. (among others) They all tell me which episodes are available and which are already played. Everything is a horrible mess, ofcourse. My iPod is somewhat in sync with my desktop, but everything else is a random jungle.

The same problem with e-mail is solved by IMAP. Every device gets content and meta-information from one server, and stays in sync with it. Per device, I can set preferences (do or do not download the complete archive including junkmail).

Can we implement the IMAP approach for podcasts? Or is there a better metaphore/standard to solve this problem? How will the adoption-strategy look like?

(by the way: except for the Windows smartphone, I own a full Apple-stack of products. Even then, I run into this problem)

**UPDATE** The RSS-to-Imap link to sourceforge looks promesting, but very alpha/experimental.

**UPDATE 2** The one thing RSS is missing is the command/method/parameter/attribute to delete/unread items. RSS can only add, not remove. If RSS(N+1) (3?) could add a value for unread="true|false", it would be solved. If I cache all my RSS-feeds on my own server, and add the attribute myself, I only would have to convince iTunes and every other client to respect that.

Comment: I am with you on this. When you have the addiction, you need to satisfy the craving. The problem with iPods is that iTunes takes over and you are at the mercy of that master list.

To my knowledge there is no solution like this currently. I would love to have one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podcasts are basically just RSS, so an IMAP solution doesn't totally make sense in this case.

You'd have to have your own podcast stack in order to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an opportunity to miss the point by interpreting your question too literally, but....

[RSS->IMAP Server](http://rssimapserver.sourceforge.net/) might be a good fit (if you have the resources to host it)?  I wonder if it supports attachments/enclosures.

Comment: My total podcast collection-size currently is 12 GB, including items allready played on another device. Gmail gives 7 GB, so it can fit.

Comment: Google may kill your account if they figure out you're just using it for file storage/transfer rather than actual e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Google Reader for listening to your podcasts?  If might be ideal if each device has a sufficient network available when it comes time to consume the podcast.

Comment: Google Reader is the all-online option. I do not allways have an (affordable) internet connection available. Also, I do not want to overuse my phone and underuse my iPod to spread battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since answering a question you didn't ask seems to be the norm around here, have you considered pop4?
pop4.org

Comment: Interesting, but how does this help solving the problem?

Comment: I love that comment, I use that all the time: "I don't see the answer to my question in your response." :-) What I was getting at was there are other server based solutions other than imap. But the first guy has a better answer use RSS readers.

Answer (score 0):

**[Odeo](http://odeo.com/)** used to do this before the creators of it went and started this little website called Twitter. That's how I used to manage podcasts. Whether it still does this, I do not know. I tend to keep my podcast subscriptions to one computer and an synced-up iPod.

Comment: Odeo: Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: Oh, you have to use www.odeo.com rather than odeo.com. As I said, whether it still is doing what it used to do, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [gpodder](http://gpodder.org/) - I use it and find it excellent.